# Pytorch Geometric import data from networkx

Tags: networkx, pytorch-geometric

I am wondering what is the proper way to covert a network data from networkx to PyG.

I know there is a function `torch_geometric.utils.convert.from_networkx`. But when I look at `Data(x, edge_index, y, pos)` in PyG, I found it also has some other information, such as graph-level labels `y` and node position `pos`. I am wondering how can I add these two information to networkx data?

Also, if I want the learning process include the node's position information, I think I should pass the node positions to the `x` instead of `pos`?